# Triple legend in ggplot2 with point shape, fill and color

Tags: r, ggplot2

My dataframe (see below for link) contains output from several models, which I want to "categorize" according to:

- model name (9 models) -> 9 shape fill colors
- model domain (each model has one of either of these two: "MED" or "EURO") -> two hollow shape types
- native resolution (each model has two "versions": "HR" and "LR") -> 2 shape contour colors

Additionally, a single observational dataset is also included, which should be shown with it's own color and filled shape.

So all in all I have 9x2=18 point types, each of which also has a "domain" tag, plus a single observational point type.

The following, which is the simplest thing one may start from, does not work at all. Also, I don't want to manually specify colors and shapes for each item using scale_*_manual.

```
library(ggplot2)

#Sorry for the wget, I can't seem to make load() read the url directly
system("wget https://copy.com/LrEznd8QCmzVBNyz/df_pr_PDF_alps_044.Rdata?download=1") 
load("df_pr_PDF_alps_044.Rdata?download=1") #This loads df
colnames(df) #Take a look at the columns

ggplot(data=df[which(df$PDF > 0),], aes(x=x, y=PDF)) +
geom_point(aes(shape=domain, colour=nativeresolution, fill=model), alpha=0.7, size=2)+
scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23))
```

I have tried some fixes such as those suggested here:

[ggplot2: One legend with two visual properties derived from common variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188964/ggplot2-one-legend-with-two-visual-properties-derived-from-common-variable)

[Combine legends for color and shape into a single legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410908/creating-a-ggplot-legend-with-both-color-and-shape)

[How to merge colour and shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435883/how-to-merge-colour-and-shape)

But I can't seem to find a solution to this seemingly simple problem.

Comment: Regaring shapes with 'fill' and 'contour' and "I don't want to manually specify colors and shapes for each item using `scale_*_manual`", please read `?pch`: "21:25 can be colored and filled with different colors". Thus, I think you _need_ to map the levels of your variable to `pch`:s which you define `manual`ly.

Comment: @Henrik Yes, you are completely right, 21 to 25 are the only ones that are affected by fill so I should use those. I forgot. I'll edit the example to use those shapes. Still it's not working well: all the legends are messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `override.aes` to specify one of the hollow shapes in the guides for fill and colour. Additionally, if you specify `colour = NA` for fill, you will get "just the fill" in the guide.

```
library(ggplot2)

system("wget https://copy.com/LrEznd8QCmzVBNyz/df_pr_PDF_alps_044.Rdata?download=1") 
load("df_pr_PDF_alps_044.Rdata?download=1")

ggplot(data=df[which(df$PDF > 0),],
       aes(x = x, y = PDF, shape = domain, colour = nativeresolution, fill = model)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.7, size=2) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22,23)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21, colour = NA)),
         colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)))
```

This fixes the legend but it may not be easy to read a scatter plot with three variables mapped to the points... have you considered using facets instead?

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for. override.aes does the trick. In this case, the plot looks much better if I implement more tweaks (log scale, thicker points, better colors, larger bins) but I admit it's not ideal. I've tried with facets and it looks very good. Thanks again.